# Asp.Net Boilerplate,, How to Get current Login User?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I want to get the user data which is currently logged in,, ??
I have to send current user ID to a table in database How to do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer to the Question

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the active user in the HTML?

Answer (score 13):

You can use AbpSession to get user. For that you have to inject IAbpSession.You can use the following code:

```
 AbpSession.UserId
```

Comment: As a note, you can also use the AbpSession property available if you inherited some Abp service or controller

Answer (score 6):

In custom classes use the code below to get current user id

```
public class MyClass : ITransientDependency
{
    public IAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var currentUserId = AbpSession.UserId;
        //...
    }    

}
```

In application services you don't need to inject AbpSession just use AbpSession public property

> AbpSession.TenantId
>
> AbpSession.UserId

Comment: As a note, you can also use the AbpSession property available if you inherited some Abp service or controller